# How to get the caption color of an active window in Windows 8

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, winapi, visual-c++

How can I get caption color of active window in Windows 8 ?

I tried to call `GetSysColor(COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION)` but it returns different color. It's strange because in Windows 7 it works right. Is there any other way how to get caption color of active window or color of taskbar ?

Comment: You'll want to call the theme API for this

Comment: It will return the correct value when DWM/Aero is disabled. When it's enabled, these are largely ignored, and you need to query the theme API for the images/colour gradiants.

Comment: Microsoft removed Aero from W8 so I think Aero isn't reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: they changed visual style, but they hardly changed the engine behind it. WinXP had a lot of skins and same is for Win7. For example wincustomize.com But opening different skins in Win7 and Win8 is not more different than putting different pictures as wallpapers in XP and Win7 - they  look different but they are both just jpeg on desktop

Comment: problem is that i'm not able get right color from Theme API too. I tried GetThemeSysColor(0, COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION) and also GetThemeColor with WINDOW/WP_CAPTION/CS_ACTIVE. GetThemeSysColor returns wrong color and GetThemeColor returns error. Don't you have any example how to get active caption color from Theme API ?

Comment: I found the solution! - function DwmGetColorizationColor

Comment: @user1614498: Then make it an answer and accept it!

Answer (score 2):

```
DWORD WINAPI GetSysColor(
 _In_  int nIndex
 );
```

For the `GetSysColor()` function, if the `nIndex` parameter is out of range, the return value is zero. Because zero is also a valid RGB value, you cannot use `GetSysColor()` to determine whether a system color is supported by the current platform. Instead, use the `GetSysColorBrush()` function, which returns `NULL` if the color is not supported.

[Click to see the syntax and usage.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Another option is to use the `DwmGetColorizationColor()` function which can retrieve the current color used for `Desktop Window Manager (DWM)` glass composition. This value is based on the current color scheme and can be modified by the user. Applications can listen for color changes by handling the `WM_DWMCOLORIZATIONCOLORCHANGED` notification.

```
HRESULT WINAPI DwmGetColorizationColor(
  _Out_  DWORD *pcrColorization,
  _Out_  BOOL *pfOpaqueBlend
);
```