# How to get window title bar (active and inactive) color in Windows 8?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm making a program and I need to paint a rectangle of the same color as the title bar.

If I try to get the color like this:

```cpp
ARGB rgbActiveColor = GetSysColor(COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION);
ARGB rgbInactiveColor = GetSysColor(COLOR_INACTIVECAPTION);
rgbActiveColor |= 0xFF000000;    // Because of alpha
rgbInactiveColor |= 0xFF000000;
```

I get a totally different color in Windows 8. It always returns a orange or brown color instead of the actual color (let's say, blue).

Using `DwmGetColorizationColor` works, but the color is darker because I need to eliminate alpha. I try to do it like this:

```cpp
BYTE r = ((RED * ALPHA) + (255 * (255 - ALPHA))) / 255; // R' = (R * A) + (1 - A)
BYTE g = ((GREEN * ALPHA) + (255 * (255 - ALPHA))) / 255; // G' = (G * A) + (1 - A)
BYTE b = ((BLUE * ALPHA) + (255 * (255 - ALPHA))) / 255; // B' = (B * A) + (1 - A)
```

So, my problems are:

1. I don't know how I can correctly convert the return color from ARGB to RGB
2. I don't know how to get the inactive title bar color

EDIT: My ARGB to RGB code seems to work unless I set color intensity in Control Panel to max (because somehow alpha is 0, and the color is green) or min.

EDIT2: This is not a duplicate because this is specifically about W8+.

Comment: Have you tried `COLORREF rgb = RGB((BYTE)rgbActiveColor >> 16, (BYTE)rgbActiveColor >> 8, (BYTE)rgbActiveColor);`

Comment: @Cyclone Yes. For some reason, the color gets green. WTF.

Comment: Okay, so I changed the color and for some reason it worked. But when I set color intensity to max (in the customizing menu), alpha is 0x00 and it all fails. Now I'm REALLY confused.

Comment: Isn't `GetSysColor()` only returning `RGB` and not `RGBA`?

Comment: @Cyclone `0xe37ebdf4` for blue with normal intensity but `0x008fd712`for max intensity. Also docs say "The color format of the value is 0xAARRGGBB."

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528228/how-to-get-the-caption-color-of-an-active-window-in-windows-8

Comment: @Cyclone I don't know what can I do anymore. `DwmGetColorizationColor` doesn't work right, `GetThemeSysColor` returns the same as `GetSysColor`, `GetThemeColor(hTheme, WP_CAPTION, CS_ACTIVE, TMT_ACTIVECAPTION, &rgbBorderColor)` returns error...

Comment: And `GetThemeColor(hTheme, WP_CAPTION, CS_ACTIVE, TMT_COLORIZATIONCOLOR, &rgbBorderColor)` returns gray.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vista/7: How to get glass color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560890/vista-7-how-to-get-glass-color)

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'm going to change the title, because this question is actually only about W8.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hackish solution and will probably only work with Windows 8 and 8.1  (I'm going to test later with 10).

I analysed the windows colors and this is what I could see:

- Active window title (or caption) color is the result of blending between `0xD9D9D9` and the color in `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM\ColorizationColor` using the value in `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM\ColorizationColorBalance` (it's in a 0-100 scale) as a "alpha".
- Inactive windows have the color 0xEBEBEB

So...

```
if (fActive)
{
    DWORD ColorizationColor;
    DWORD ColorizationColorBalance;
    DWORD size = sizeof(DWORD);

    RegGetValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\DWM", L"ColorizationColor", RRF_RT_REG_DWORD, 0, &ColorizationColor, &size);
    RegGetValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\DWM", L"ColorizationColorBalance", RRF_RT_REG_DWORD, 0, &ColorizationColorBalance, &size);

    BYTE ALPHA = 255 * ColorizationColorBalance / 100; // Convert from 0-100 to 0-255
    BYTE RED = (ColorizationColor >> 16) & 0xFF;
    BYTE GREEN = (ColorizationColor >> 8) & 0xFF;
    BYTE BLUE = ColorizationColor & 0xFF;

    BYTE r = ((RED * ALPHA) + (0xD9 * (255 - ALPHA))) / 255;
    BYTE g = ((GREEN * ALPHA) + (0xD9 * (255 - ALPHA))) / 255;
    BYTE b = ((BLUE * ALPHA) + (0xD9 * (255 - ALPHA))) / 255;

    graphics.FillRectangle(&SolidBrush(Color(r, g, b)), Rect(...);
}
else
{
    graphics.FillRectangle(&SolidBrush(0xFFEBEBEB), Rect(...));
}
```

Because this probably won't work at Windows 7 different code should be user for different systems.